# Dynamically add items to jquery slideshow

Tags: jquery, slideshow, slidesjs

I'm trying to add items to a jquery slideshow ( [slides](http://slidesjs.com/) ) but i can't find a way to refresh it.
I have this html code:

```
<a class='add' href='#'>add slide</a>

<div id="slides">   
    <div class="slides_container">    
            <h1>Slide 1</h1>       
            <h1>Slide 2</h1>       
            <h1>Slide 3</h1>       
            <h1>Slide 4</h1>       
            <h1>Slide 5</h1>       
   </div>
</div>
```

and this js:

```
$(function() {
    $("#slides").slides();

    $('.add').live('click', (function() {
        $('.slides_control').append('<h1>Slide added</h1>');
        // note: slides_control div is added by the slides plugin automatically and is the real container of the items.
        return false;
    }));

});
```

The demo is in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oterox/Bahsq/)

I need to reload the slideshow to show new data but i can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newest version of Slides ([see Github](https://github.com/nathansearles/Slides)) actually does have a function `slides('update')`, but the current version doesn't have that yet.

In the meantime, you can use this little hack:

```
$("#slides").slides();

$('.add').on('click', function() {
    var children = $('#slides .slides_control').children();
    var newContainer = $('<div class="slides_container" />');
    var slides = $('#slides');

    slides.empty().append(newContainer);
    newContainer.append(children);
    newContainer.append('<div><h1>New slide</h1></div>');

    slides.slides();

    return false;
});
```

You can play with it here: **http://jsfiddle.net/R7zvM/**

Please note that you should probably do some testing before using this in production code. It seems pretty stable, but your mileage may vary.

**P.S.** the [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7. In this example you did't need event delegation, anyway, but if you ever do you should use the new syntax:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.add', function() {
    console.log('Do something');
});
```

Comment: that works great!!! I'm going to check github to test the newest version too.Thk very much

Answer (score 0):

Try `$("#slides").slides("update");`

Comment: it doesn't work.I've added it before "return false". I can't find the "update" option in their documentation.